# AJAX: Posts are sent empty

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using AJAX for the first time and try to send data to my PHP controller with an XMLHttpRequest. Unfortunately, the data arrives empty there.

```
           request.onload = () => {
                let responseObject = null;

                try {
                    responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Could not parse JSON!');
                }

                if (responseObject) {
                    handleResponse(responseObject);
                }
            };

            const requestData = `title=${this._title.value}&reference=${this._reference.value}&area=${this._area.value}`;

            request.open('post', 'checknews');
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            request.send(requestData);
```

Whats wrong ?

Comment: What does `requestData` contain? Are the values you are inserting there properly URL encoded?

Comment: Have you inspected Network tab? Can you post it's cUrl export here? Maybe you read it wrong on server side?

Comment: Yes, the status code is 'OK' -> Response: `{"ok":false,"messages":["News ben\u00f6tigen einen Titel!","Gibt es etwa nichts neues?"],"title":"","reference":"","area":""}
___________________ On Server Side _________________
 $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
    $refrence = isset($_POST['reference']) ? $_POST['reference'] : '';
    $area = isset($_POST['area']) ? $_POST['area'] : '';`

Comment: idk why, but the Request Method is "GET" .. doesn't it have to be "POST" ?